# How to properly zip a macos .app file with zip command?

Tags: macos, shell, zip, compression

`zip -r foo.zip foo.app` zips a 12md app into a 12md `.zip` file, and it becomes a 34mb `.app` file after unzipping. How to properly zip a `.app` file with zip command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute command:

```
# Basic command: zip [Flags] archiveFileName [inpaths]
$sudo zip -9 -y -r -q Acc.zip Adobe\ Acrobat\ Reader\ DC.app
```

Flag descriptions:
-9: compress better
-y: store symbolic links as the link instead of the referenced file
-r: recurse into directories
-q: quiet operation

Size of Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.app: 512.5 MB
[image]

Size of compressed file Acc.zip: 215.4MB[image]

Decompressed file size of Acc.zip file: 512.5MB
[image]

Comment: This is working, thanks. I should look more into the man page of zip